# Time constraint on a sql trigger

Tags: sql, oracle11g, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following table called `employees`

```
create table employees 
(
   eno      number(4) not null primary key, 
   ename    varchar2(30),
   zip      number(5) references zipcodes,
   hdate    date
);
```

And I'm trying to set a trigger on the table that will fire before an `update or delete` that will check the system time first to see if the time is between 12:00-13:00, if it is it will allow the insertion, otherwise prevent it.

My guess is so far:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER twelve_one 
BEFORE INSERT or Update ON employees
BEGIN
 IF
  ....
 ELSE
  ....
END;
```

But that's how far I've gotten into unfortunately. Can someone please help me to retrieve the system time first? Then how can I set up that `IF ELSE` block? And finally How to abort the transaction/insertion/update? 
I'm using Oracle SQL Developer 4.02.15
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you must declare temporary variable to set time now, and then compare the temporary variable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TWELVE_ONE
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON EMPLOYEES
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
      V_DATE   VARCHAR2 (10);
BEGIN
          SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') INTO V_DATE FROM DUAL;
      IF (V_DATE >= '12:00:01' AND V_DATE < '13:00:00')
          THEN
              INSERT INTO TABLE .. 
           ELSE
              UPDATE TABLE...
      END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Here dual call is neccessary.

Comment: Pardon my prev comment. I said dual call can be avoided

Comment: @Melkikun I'll accept it as answer and its excellent! Thank You! However, how is it possible to pass the values here?
 I mean lets say my create statement is:

 `Insert into employees Values (1, 'someone', 11111, '17-12-2015')`

And lets say the time is 12:30:01 now. How would the trigger perform the insertion without knowing the values?

And lets say the time is now 13:00:1 now. How would the trigger stop/prevent the insertion?